# Python: Disable images in Selenium Ms.Edge (chromium) Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have spent a long time searching for this answer. I want to open a website without loading images using Selenium Python. I'm confused about looking for variables to adjust browser settings.

this is my code that I know to set the capabilitise

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_capability("dom.webnotifications.enabled", 1)
capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Edge(capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com/")
daftar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-main-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[5]/button[1]')


actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(daftar).perform()
```

and I know that this is the code to disable images using Chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

so, how to set edge options with selenium python. I really don't know about this.

thank you

Comment: I found the answer myself after finding msedge.selenium_tools

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself after finding msedge.selenium_tools

this is my code that actually work perfectky to block the image

```
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = Edge(options = options)

driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com")
daftar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-main-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[5]/button[1]')


actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(daftar).perform()
```